# labeling pie chart issue with ggplot2 (and chage grom text to label)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have the following problem: I can't add correctly a label on a pie chart using ggplot2 in R.

This is the code:

```
establecimientos <- c("A", "A","A","D","D","D","D","D","D","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","G","G","G","G","G","Y","Y","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B")


pestab <- data.frame(establecimientos) %>% 
  group_by(establecimientos) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n(),
         pct = percent(cnt / nrow(.), accuracy = 1)) %>%
  unique %>% ungroup %>% 
  mutate(place = cumsum(cnt) - cnt/2) %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., 
         aes(x = factor(1), weight = cnt, fill = factor(establecimientos))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, length(establecimientos), length(establecimientos)/4), 
                     labels = c("0", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) + 
  coord_polar(theta='y') +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.3, y = place, label = pct)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(fill = "Establecimientos")

pestab
```

And this is the product =s

[image: pie chart with labeling problems]

Additionally, I want to change from geom_text to geom_label but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data 1
establecimientos <- c("A", "A","A","D","D","D","D","D","D","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","G","G","G","G","G","Y","Y","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B")
#Data 2
df1 <- pestab <- data.frame(establecimientos) %>% 
  group_by(establecimientos) %>% 
  mutate(cnt = n(),
         pct = percent(cnt / nrow(.), accuracy = 1)) %>%
  unique %>% ungroup %>% 
  mutate(place = cumsum(cnt) - cnt/2)
#Plot
ggplot(df1,aes(x = "", y = cnt, fill = establecimientos)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, length(establecimientos), length(establecimientos)/4), 
                     labels = c("0", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"))+
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  geom_text(
    aes(y = cnt, label = pct), 
    color = "black", 
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(fill = "Establecimientos")
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to use `geom_label()` you can use next code:

```
#Plot 2
ggplot(df1,aes(x = "", y = cnt, fill = establecimientos)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, length(establecimientos), length(establecimientos)/4), 
                     labels = c("0", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"))+
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  geom_label(
    aes(y = cnt, label = pct), 
    color = "black", 
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),show.legend = F
  )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(fill = "Establecimientos")
```

Output:

[image]